# Obtendo valor de TD e colocando-o no array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso obter o valor de uma td e coloca-la no array como no exemplo a seguir:

```js
 function finalizaCompra() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tblItens");
    var produto = [];
    if (tbl != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                produto[j] = tbl.rows[i].cells[j];
             console.log(produto[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="tblItens">
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> 2 </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<img src = "http://img.freepik.com/icones-gratis/carrinho-de-compras-lado-vazio-vista_318-50806.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg" onclick="finalizaCompra()" width="100" height="100" />
```

Porém retorna como indefinido, podem me ajudar?

Comment: Tem que ser com javascript puro ou pode ter jQuery ?

Comment: Pode ser jQuery, sem problemas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode obter os elementos `td` que deseja com o `querySelectorAll`, percorrer a lista retornada e adicionar ao *array* o valor do atributo `innerHTML`. Veja um exemplo:

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("#tblItens td");
const values = [];

tds.forEach(td => {
  values.push(td.innerHTML);
});

console.log(values);
```

```html
<table id="tblItens">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Se precisar do valor como inteiro, basta colocar `parseInt(td.innerHTML, 10))` no `push` do *array*.

Com o ES6, você pode simplificar um pouco o código utilizando as reticências para converter a `NodeList` retornada pela `querySelectorAll` em um *array* e mapeá-la, fazendo:

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("#tblItens td");
const values = [...tds].map(td => td.innerHTML);

console.log(values);
```

```html
<table id="tblItens">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito bom !!! Estou em duvida agora, ambas respostas me explicaram muitas coisas

Comment: Dou como resolvido para qual resposta? kkk

Answer (score 2):

Sua função está quase correta, exceto por dois problemas:

**1º. Pegar somente o texto da célula:**

Faltou o `textContent` em `produto[j] = tbl.rows[i].cells[j];` para pegar somente o texto dentro da célula. O correto seria: `produto[j] = tbl.rows[i].cells[j].textContent;`

**2º. Valor inválido no `j`:**

```
console.log(produto[j]);
```

Quando você chama o `j` após o laço `for` ter sido concluído, ele finaliza a variável `j` com um valor a mais do que o tamanho da array, por isso está retornando `undefined`.

Seu código correto seria:

```
function finalizaCompra() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tblItens");
    var produto = [];
    if (tbl != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                produto[j] = tbl.rows[i].cells[j].textContent;
                console.log(produto); // irá retornar toda a array
        }
    }
}
```

```js
function finalizaCompra() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tblItens");
    var produto = [];
    if (tbl != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                produto[j] = tbl.rows[i].cells[j].textContent;
             console.log(produto);
        }
    }
}
finalizaCompra();
```

```html
<table id="tblItens">
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> 2 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação DvD !!!

Comment: @Sora De nada amiga! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A solução na resposta do Anderson é mais simples, mas segue uma opção utilizando jQuery:

```js
 var data = [];
 $('#tblItens').find("tr").each(function (i, el) {
        var row = [];
        var td = $(this).find('td');
        row.push(td.eq(0).text());
        row.push(td.eq(1).text());
        data.push(row);
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblItens">
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> 2 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> 3 </td>
  <td> 4 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito bom !!! Estou em duvida agora, ambas respostas me explicaram muitas coisas

Comment: Dou como resolvido para qual resposta? kkk

Comment: A do Anderson é com javascript puro, está mais no contexto de sua pergunta.